# I can't see my SharedFolder

Tags: mount

I started a VM (host : Windows 10 guest : Ubuntu 20.04) a few days ago and created a shared Folder. I selected auto-mount  and I think I followed the steps correctly but it is simply not there and if I want to join the vboxsf group it says the group does't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a group, use the `groupadd` or `addgroup` command. See `man groupadd` or `man addgroup` for more info.

If you've added the Ubuntu user to the vboxsf group, then you have to log the user out of Ubuntu, then log back in, for it to be seen.

Then open a `Files` (Navigator) window and look in the left pane for sf_SharedFolder. Click on it once to see the contents.

Comment: I can't add the user to the group because the terminal says the group does not exist

Comment: @TomRiddle Use the `groupadd` command. See `man groupadd` for more info.

Comment: @TomRiddle Status please...